# Wearing tefilin all the time included Shabbat?

Tags: minhag, shabbat, tefilin

When people used to [wear tefilin every day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9462/1713), did they do so on Shabbat as well?  If so, why did people stop wearing tefilin on Shabbat? If not, why not?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31651/5

Comment: It's permissible to wear tafillin on shabboth without taking them off because you will be carrying them which is ossur daoraitho. Therefore rather leave them on if you know for sure that you will be carrying them on shabboth otherwise.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob That's when you wear them as jewelry, not for the Mitzva.

Comment: @double it starts from wearing them as a mee9woh but you didn't know shabboth was approaching n it's too late now to take then off so you wear them on shabboth. Not sure if its considered jewelry or not.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob It can start however you want it to start. It can even apply if you find them in the middle of no where and want to bring them back to a safe place. That rule has nothing to do with the Mitzva.

Answer (score 5):

Menachos 36b - Rabbi Yosi & Rabbi Akiva say that it is forbidden to put on Tefilin on Shabbos. The reason according to Rabbi Akiva is that Shabbos is instead the sign of Tefilin.

[Please see here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_20741_162.pdf) regarding the need of having two signs every day of our Jewishness. The two signs are Bris & Tefilin. On Shabbos since Shabbos is a sign, Tefilin is not necessary.

Comment: +1 We do paskin שבת לאו זמן תפילין but see other Tannaitic opinions on Eruvin 96.